# Hide a ',' comma that repeats multiple times on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, replace

I'm trying to hide a `','` (comma) that appears multiple times on a CMS-generated page. See the page here:

http://www.ucd.ie/earth/sandbox/test/01.html

I have tried the following code just before the  tag (without success):

```
<script language="javascript">
var container = $(".hide-comma");
var result = container.html().replace(/,/g, "");
container.html(result);
</script>
```

Comment: Is it the `hide-comma` div that needs to have the comma hidden?

Comment: Where _precisely_ within the HTML are commas you want to remove? There is **no content** in **any** DIV with id `.hide-comma` in that sample. Your code may or may not be working properly, but one should start by modifying content that actually exists? What am I missing? (My bet is you mean the `.team-info` DIV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the below code after load page completed:

```
 $('.team-description').each(function(i , v){
     var t = $(v).html().replace(/,/g, '');
     $(v).html(t);
 });
```

and see below link
https://jsfiddle.net/sajjadgol/xpvt214o/881975/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to replace all the "," inside the div. so you can do like this.. get html inside the div then replace all the ','

```js
function replaceComma(){

  $('#divWithComma').html($('#divWithComma').html().replace(",",""));
  console.log('replaced the comma, if you want to see hiding the comma please run the snippet again');
}

function hideComma(){
  
  let text = $('#divWithComma').html();
  let stringArray = text.split(',');
  let finalHtml = "";
  
  for(let i = 0; i<stringArray.length-1; i++){
    finalHtml += stringArray[i] + '<span style="display:none;aria-hidden=true">,</span><p></p>';
  }
  
  $('#divWithComma').html(finalHtml);
  
  console.log("yes hide the comma");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='divWithComma'>
  <p>,</p>
  <input type='button' onclick='replaceComma()' value='replace comma' />
  <input type='button' onclick='hideComma()' value='hide comma' />
</div>
```

Comment: please add `aria-hidden="true"` next tho style="display:none", accessiblity is easy to achieve and can help a lot of people for free.

Comment: Many thanks for your code. In the end I used the shorter option given. I really appreciate your time taken to write.